# jenkin git clone error

Tags: git, github, jenkins

Not able to clone git repo in jenkin. Getting below error( same job was working fine and there are no changes to the git repo)

```
Cloning repository origin
Error trying to determine the git version: Error performing command:  --version
null
Assuming 1.6
ERROR: Error cloning remote repo 'origin' : Could not clone git@github.xxx.git
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Could not clone git@github.xxx.git
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitAPI.clone(GitAPI.java:245)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM$2.invoke(GitSCM.java:1073)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM$2.invoke(GitSCM.java:1014)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:865)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:838)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1014)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1353)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:689)
    at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:88)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:594)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1567)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:46)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:237)
Caused by: hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Error performing command:  clone -o origin git@github.xxx.git /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/xxx/yyy
null
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitAPI.launchCommandIn(GitAPI.java:776)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitAPI.access$000(GitAPI.java:38)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitAPI$1.invoke(GitAPI.java:241)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitAPI$1.invoke(GitAPI.java:221)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:865)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:838)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitAPI.clone(GitAPI.java:221)
    ... 13 more
```

Comment: Do the plugin need git installed in the system?

Comment: Where are you setting git path? Check - Manage Jenkins > Configure System settings > Git > "Path to Git executable" to /usr/bin/git (put in your path). Otherwise you can set it into node settings.

Comment: I'm setting though Manage Jenkins' option

Answer (score 0):

You have to install [jenkins git plugin](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/git/)

Answer (score 0):

Check belows

1. Check you have installed Git plugin.
2. Check you have configured Jenkin to use local git (Since your command doesn't start with Git command, incase not, set Git path in Jenkin).
3. Check weather Git is configured to bypass SSL Configuration, Refer "[Jenkins Git integration - How to disable SSL certificate validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41930608/jenkins-git-integration-how-to-disable-ssl-certificate-validation/53993422#53993422)"