# How to disable certificate verify on Jenkins's workSpace/Slave

Tags: git, jenkins, github, github-api

I am using Git as Source Code Management(SCM) in Jenkins. (using a GitHub Token)

However, whenever I run the job, I get `stderr: fatal: unable to access '<url>': SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate` error.

`git config --global http.sslVerify false` does not solve the issue.

Because in Jenkins,  `SCM` is the first step for the job.

Comment: Are you using ssh key as GitHub repository URL in Jenkins configuration?

Comment: @bot  no, I am using the standard http URL

Answer (score 0):

> but in Jenkins, it doesn't work because SCM is the first step for the job.

It should still work, unless the SCM step is done on the agent side.

In which case you might consider:

- the same global Git config done on the agent workstation
- launching the agent with (as [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53666882/6309))

  ```
  export GIT_SSL_NO_VERIFY=true

  java -Dorg.jenkinsci.plugins.getclient.GitClient.untrustedSSL=true -jar slave.jar \
       -jnlpUrl ${jenkins_url}/computer/${slave_name}/slave-agent.jnlp -secret ${secret} \
       -noCertificateCheck
  ```

Comment: where should I put this command `git config --global http.sslVerify false`. I forgot to mention that I was putting it in `Build` - `Execute Shell`

Comment: @RayZ The SCM step is separate and preced the build step. The global config would be done on the server and on the agent, with the user running Jenkins.